# SpriteKit: How to spawn object in exact place?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm in the middle of making a simple game in XCode 7, using sprite kit. I currently have a square in the middle of the scene and I have set up swipe gestures which make smaller squares "shoot" out of the left, right, top of bottom of the square, depending on the way of the swipe gesture. They go in a straight direction and I would like other random "Enemy" squares to come in the opposite way, again in the same line of path as the squares that are shot out so they can collide... Any ideas on how to do this?

Here's the basic idea, same for the right, up and down:

```
func swipedLeft(){

        print("SwipedLeft")

        let SmallSquare1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Square")
        SmallSquare1.position = MainSquare.position
        SmallSquare1.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        SmallSquare1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: SmallSquare1.size.width / 2)
        SmallSquare1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        self.addChild(SmallSquare1)

        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 2)

        SmallSquare1.runAction(moveLeft)
```

Here's the Enemy function I'm stuck on...

```
func Enemies(){
    let Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Square")
    Enemy.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    Enemy.color = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)
    Enemy.colorBlendFactor = 1.0

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the one on the left:

```
Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: (any X position), y: MainSquare.position.y)
```

And do the same for the right side.

And for above and below just do the MainSquare.position.x as the x position